# SymmetricDS synch from view

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, data-synchronization, symmetricds

I'm looking at the features of SymmetricDS (last version symmetric-server-3.7.24) and in their forum I read it is actually possibile to synch from a view.
So I tried to synch from a view but when I run the program I got an error because symmetricDs cannot create a trigger on the view.
I also read that if a use a materialized view, then the trigger should be created.

The view is on a sqlserver 2008. I dropped the view and create a new one with schemabinding and add a cluster index on it. I also check that all the options are set as required in the MSDN guide to create indexed table.

I run symmetricDS again but still fail to create the trigger on the view.

Can anyone help me?
If what I ask is actually not possibile, then it is possibile to craete an extension that does not use trigger to synchronized the tables? I don't care that the two db are synched realtime, I can use a scheduled job, it will be just fine.

Thank you for you help and suggestion.

BTW: I can also change tool you you know a better one :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's a supported use case.  However, you can try setting the sync_on_insert/update/delete fields to 0 on the sym_trigger.  Then you would be able to sync the view with an initial load or by scheduling reloads (see "symadmin reload-table" command).

Comment: Thank you! It works! I set sync_on_insert/update/delete fields to 0 on the sym_trigger and then, since I'm on sqlserver, I used a scheduled job to populate the sym_table_reload_request and send the records of the view to the target db. Thank you very much for the help!